# Manipulate JavaScript files with TypeScript/NodeJs dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, substitution

I want to process some manipulation on existing HTML/JS files automatically. For HTML DOM manipulation we have librarys like [cheerio](https://cheerio.js.org/). But how can I dynamically manipulate plain JS files?

**Example of a original file (lets call it original.js)**

```
version = '1.0';
var config = {
    loginUrl: '/homepage/login',
    defaultLanguage: 'en-us'
}
// ... More JS Code
```

I want to automatically change the config in the code so that we have e.g. **modified.js**

```
version = '1.0';
var config = {
    loginUrl: '/other-link/login',
    defaultLanguage: 'de-de'
}
// ... More JS Code
```

It would be nice to have some clean parsing lib like we have for HTML, instead of doing some error-prone replacing with strings or regexp.

### Why do we need such nasty modifications?

I have a proprietary IBM Connections extension that is delivered in a zip file. We need to customize some things in the javascript files like changing the default language from english to german. Sadly the codebase isn't really clean. For example we don't have a dedicated js config file that can be easily customized. Instead there is a config array within a large code file (about ~1k lines of code).

To increase maintainability when the original app got updated, I want to do as few manual changes as possible on the original source code. That's the reason I want to automate this: In the example above, I want to outsource the config array in a single js file outside the proprietary code base and write a nodejs application that replaces the original array by my custom one.

So we can relatively simply update the original application without doing much core changes by hand. I know that this is only a workaround for a bad designed system. But since I'm not the developer of the original one, I can't change it and want to do my required modifications as clean as possible.

Comment: Can the integrated `file system` library into `nodejs` not help you out? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_writestream

Comment: You could parse your code into AST, and transform.  It's not as hard as you might think, have a look at Babel.io, and writing AST plugins.

Comment: @Tarabass The problem is not how to fetch the js file content, but how to do the substitution. Having the content, I need to replace things on my own using regex/substrings and similar things. It would be cleaner to have some kind of lib where I can tell to replace e.g. the `config` object with another object defined by me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node.js then there is a npm module namely ts-simple-ast which gives you the parsed version of the typescript file and then there are tons of functions through which you can access the particular node. You can also manipulate the file by using their getters and setters functions after traversing to a particular node.

Now the liberary is changed to [ts-morph](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-morph). Have a look into this npm module.
And you can easily easily replace the config object with another object.